# Delete all orders and quotes of customers that do not exist anymore

Tags: orders, quote, programmatically, delete

On our testing environment we are constantly creating new customers and also (mass) removing them again, currently only having 12 customers. Now after a while our `sales_flat_order` (5038 rows) and `sales_flat_quote` (5279 rows) tables are really filling up. I want to clean them up with a simple script or SQL query (maybe going to put this in a cron too). Does anyone know how to do this and not miss anything in the clean up?

Comment: You might be interested in these SQL statements: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3703/231. That truncates of course all of the orders and does not take care of existing customers.