# Magento 2: How to truncate customers, products, reviews and orders table

Tags: magento2, testing

Does anyone have list of tables I need to truncate to delete all test customers, products, reviews and orders in Magento 2 ? I'm looking for something similar to [Clearing Magento after testing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/clearing-magento-after-testing) .

Comment: This should help for order deletion https://magecomp.com/magento-2-delete-orders.html

Comment: i just used all queries from @amitshree's answer. But i saw some table still have many data: +-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+ | Table | Rows | +-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+ | catalog_product_attribute_cl | 29613 | | catalogrule_product_cl | 31850 | | url_rewrite | 98607 | | sequence_product | 178345 | | targetrule_product_rule_cl | 1944 | | email_catalog | 99064 | | catalog_product_index_price_replica | 395031 | | cataloginventory_stock_status_replica | 56320 | | catalogsearch_fulltext_cl | 14524 | | catalog_product

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142066)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**[Note]**: Please take database backup prior to executing these queries.

I went through all tables and came up with the following list of tables that should be truncated in order to clear test data:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**Truncate order tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
```

**Truncate Customer tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option`;
```

**Truncate Review tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `review`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_detail`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_entity_summary`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_store`;
```

**Truncate Product tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
```

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: After truncating tables this way, I get an `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_STOCK_ID_CATINV_STOCK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `cataloginventory_stock` (`stock_id`) ON DELETE CASC)` error when trying to add/save product. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Tom  I've faced this error too. If you do not truncate `cataloginventory_stock` table it will work fine.

Comment: Don't try this. because grouped product will not get created after executing this query.

Comment: @saravanavelu: why so? why table will create the issue?

Comment: It tries to order by 'position' column, which is not exists. Did you tried to create grouped product after executing this query?

Comment: I haven't tried creating grouped product but I'll look into it.

Comment: Dears, did you fin a fix for creating grouped products, I am facing that issue

Comment: Can I suggest adding the newsletter_subscriber table also to the Customer list of tables as this contains personal information also. TRUNCATE TABLE `newsletter_subscriber`;

Comment: worked for me for orders confirmed and code can be reusable for orders! +1 perfect answer!!! :)

Comment: @amitshree, will it start from id 1?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, Yes. That's the beauty of truncate.

Comment: @amitshree, Thanks, can you update for truncating categories also? and for products do we need to remove media/catalog folders completely to remove the images?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, truncating category is not straight-forward because it will delete root category too. Though you can follow [David's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103247/9169) to truncate it. It will be better if you clean your catalog media folder though it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 11):

Clearing all reviews:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `rating_option_vote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `rating_option_vote_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_detail`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_entity_summary`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_store`;
```

Clearing all customers:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE `customer_entity_varchar`;

ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Clearing all products:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,0,'Default');
```

Clearing all orders, shipments, transactions etc.:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: It is not removing order increment id.

Answer (score 6):

**TRUNCATE CUSTOMERS**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
DELETE FROM customer_address_entity WHERE 1;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
DELETE FROM customer_entity WHERE 1;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
DELETE FROM wishlist WHERE 1;
DELETE FROM wishlist_item WHERE 1;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option`;
```

Answer (score 4):

Magento 2.2.6 over here, had to clean database after a bin/magento sampledata:remove.

Short story long, SQL above for **orders**, **customers** and **reviews** are still working (remember to add `ALTER TABLE xxx AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`) but I had to tweak some stuff for **categories** and **products**.

I believe this new summary can help anyone else :

**CATEGORIES**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DELETE FROM `m_url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` = 'category';

TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_flat_store_1`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_flat_store_2`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store1`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store2`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store2_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;

ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_flat_store_1` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_flat_store_2` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store1` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store2` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_store2_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `m_catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '0', '0', '1'),
('2', '3', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1/2', '1', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO `m_catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
('1', '69', '0', '1', '1'),
('2', '46', '0', '2', '1'),
('3', '69', '0', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `m_catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
('1', '45', '0', '1', 'Root Catalog'),
('2', '45', '0', '2', 'Default Category'),
('3', '52', '0', '2', 'PRODUCTS');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

**PRODUCTS**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DELETE FROM `m_url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` = 'product';

TRUNCATE TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_flat_1`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_flat_2`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_frontend_action`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity`;

ALTER TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_status` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_cataloginventory_stock` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_category_product_index_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_compare_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_option_value` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_price_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_selection` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_selection_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_bundle_stock_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_gallery` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_link` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_link_type` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_type_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_type_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_option_type_value` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_super_attribute` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_super_link` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_eav_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_price_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_tier_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_index_website` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_website` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_flat_1` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_flat_2` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_frontend_action` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_link` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_link_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_link_purchased` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_link_purchased_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_link_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_sample` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_downloadable_sample_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_product_alert_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_product_alert_stock` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_report_compared_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_report_viewed_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `m_catalog_product_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT  INTO `m_catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `m_catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `m_cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,0,'Default');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

For Clearing the user details from the database you can do the below steps.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

This will remove all the users and start entity id from 1.

Answer (score 3):

**TRUNCATE CATEGORIES AND CREATING A ROOT CATEGORY**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', '2016-06-23 00:00:00', '2016-06-23 00:00:00', '1', '0', '0', '1'), ('2', '3', '1', '2016-06-23 00:00:00', '2016-06-23 00:00:00', '1/2', '1', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_datetime` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('1', '58', '0', '1', NULL), (2, 58, 0, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_decimal` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 69, 0, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('1', '66', '0', '1', '1'), (2, 43, 0, 2, 1), (3, 50, 0, 2, NULL), (4, 51, 0, 2, 1), (5, 66, 0, 2, 1), (6, 68, 0, 2, 0);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_text` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('1', '64', '0', '1', NULL), (2, 64, 0, 2, NULL), (3, 44, 0, 2, NULL), (4, 47, 0, 2, NULL), (5, 48, 0, 2, NULL), (6, 61, 0, 2, NULL);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('1', '42', '0', '1', 'Root Catalog');
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (2, 42, 0, 2, 'Default Category'), (3, 46, 0, 2, NULL), (4, 49, 0, 2, 'PRODUCTS'), (5, 57, 0, 2, NULL), (6, 60, 0, 2, NULL), (7, 65, 0, 2, NULL), (8, 113, 0, 2, 'default-category'), (9, 114, 0, 2, NULL), (10, 143, 0, 2, NULL), (11, 145, 0, 2, NULL), (12, 147, 0, 2, NULL);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

**TRUNCATE CATEGORIES**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;


INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,0,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0); 
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,32,0,2,1),(2,32,1,2,1); 
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,33,0,2,'default-category');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not truncate `catalog_product_link_attribute` table, else you will encounter an issue on creating grouped products. Except that, you can truncate other tables as mentioned by @amitshree 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102995/14787

**If you already truncated that table, insert records as below:-**

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute` VALUES (1,1,'position','int'),(2,4,'position','int'),(3,5,'position','int'),(4,3,'position','int'),(5,3,'qty','decimal');
```

Answer (score 2):

This correct one

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

Comment: Using Truncate is better because it also resets auto-increment value, so your new items will have their IDs starting from 1 again.

Comment: ok  i will  try @Ziki

Answer (score 1):

After truncating the category tables you might get duplicate entry errors for URL keys so you need to clear category URL keys from `url_rewrite` table.

```
DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` = 'category'
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's answers are great, but I would like to add that it is CRITICAL for the Auto Increments to be reset when these tables are truncated. Normally MySQL does this automatically, but in two separate environments, I had countless issues with this NOT getting reset. I used REGEX to find and replace the above answers to add an ALTER TABLE after each TRUNCATE. Most of the above symptoms / issues were seen until I reset the AUTO_INCREMENTS on all the truncated tables.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to truncate the archive tables as well

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `magento_sales_order_grid_archive`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `magento_sales_shipment_grid_archive`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `magento_sales_invoice_grid_archive`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `magento_sales_creditmemo_grid_archive`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DELETE FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `entity_type` = 'product';

TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_replica`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_frontend_action`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sequence_product`;

ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_compare_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_link` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_link_type` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_super_link` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_replica` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_index_website` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_website` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_frontend_action` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_sample` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_sample_title` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `product_alert_price` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `product_alert_stock` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_viewed_product_index` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,0,'Default');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For all customers tables all need to do is truncate `customer_entity` TABLE as it will REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE on all other tables apart from `customer_grid_flat`, `customer_log`, customer_visitor