# magento 2.1 can not create grouped product

Tags: grouped-products

I can not create grouped product from the admin panel it gives the below error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'position' in 
'order clause', query was: SELECT `e`.*, `at_status`.`value` AS 
`status`, `links`.`link_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER 
JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON 
(`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
(`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_link` AS `links` ON links.linked_product_id
= e.entity_id AND links.link_type_id = 3 INNER JOIN 
`catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity_table` ON links.product_id = 
product_entity_table.entity_id WHERE (((`e`.`required_options` != 1) OR
(`e`.`required_options` IS NULL))) AND (at_status.value IN(1, 2)) AND 
(links.product_id = 687) AND (`e`.`entity_id` != '687') ORDER BY 
`position` ASC
```

What caused that error, Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I have used that [sql statements](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102995/47131) to clear the DB from products, customers and categories prior to deploy

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because the last part of the query is ambiguous:

```
ORDER BY `position` ASC
```

I don't know if you're using custom or community modules, or if this is just core code, but to fix it, I recommend troubleshooting the code that's creating the query and ensuring that all columns are specified correctly. It should look like:

```
ORDER BY table_alias.`position` ASC
```

where `table_alias` is replaced with the name or alias of the table that this column is coming from.

Hope this helps. Your question doesn't have lots of details, and it sounds like this is an issue with custom code, so if you could post any of that, that would be helpful...

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4621#issuecomment-269324410

thanks to sumanta-cn .