# Magento2 import csv file get error interity constraint

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog, importexport, import-products

Im  upload bulk products successfully  afterthat im delete all products  use this command  in my catlog

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

afterthat im try to re upload products im getting an error like this

```
General system exception happened
Additional data: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'ceratizit-11759716-spun-120308-inserts-for-turning.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `url_rewrite` (`redirect_type`,`is_autogenerated`,`metadata`,`description`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),
```

[image]
How resolve this Error
Need Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to you have not removed entries for the **product URL Keys** from **url_rewrite** table. Moreover it is not a proper way to delete a product because by doing this you are just removing entries from main product table where as all other tables will have data related to those products and it will duplicate data in related tables. Apart from that your table size also will increase due to dumping of data which is unused as you delete entries from main table.

You can check following link to delete a data from DB.

[Magento 2: How to truncate customers, products, reviews and orders table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/magento-2-how-to-truncate-customers-products-reviews-and-orders-table)

Comment: Bro plz tell me the particular solution steps  im new in magento  Need help

Comment: Just remove the entries in url_rewrite table first. For that you need to find url_keys for those products you have imported.

Comment: hello Mr.salma saiyad  how can remove decimal point in layed navigation price it shows like 11.9999999999 Need Help

Comment: Hi, Can i know which version of magento 2 you are using? And i am Miss Salma.

Comment: hi mr.salma im using mageno 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Please take backup of database before working-
follow the following steps-

1- open your database and truncate tables using command

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `url_rewrite`;
```

2- perform you CSV import

3- Generate new URL using following extension

```
https://github.com/Iazel/magento2-regenurl
```