# Delete test orders Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales, delete

I've done some orders through Magento however I want to remove them now from Sales page to clean it up. I need to remove only test orders, there are also some real order which I don't wish to remove.

What approach shall I take?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: How to truncate customers, products, reviews and orders table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/magento-2-how-to-truncate-customers-products-reviews-and-orders-table)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have real orders in the database I don't wish to remove. Plus I only wish to remove the orders. Not products, not reviews, just the orders.

Comment: then you have to delete test orders manually, or you can delete the test orders by id in a script

Comment: Can you please explain HOW to remove delete the test order manually? I'm unsure hence why I asked the question. Thanks

Comment: there are extensions available to delete orders, you have to use one of them

Comment: Any recommendations? I'm not really a fan of installing random plugins on Google without knowing if they're good or not.

Comment: Sorry But I have not used any of those extensions, you can check their review on Magento marketplace

Comment: You can use this extension for delete test order.
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-delete-orders

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Magento 2.1.0

Be safe : make a backup of your sql first.

Use the sql below according to your needs :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

# Clean order history
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;

# Clean order infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;

# Clean cart infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

# Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

DO NOT TRUNCATE / EMPTY THE FOLLOWING :

- sales_order_status
- sales_sequence_meta
- sales_sequence_profile
- sales_order_status_label
- sales_order_status_state

Thank you

Comment: Thsi works perfectly in 2.3.7. Needs more upvotes

Comment: Thank you
Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Removing Sample Data can easily be done through Database Queries.

I wrote a Codeblog about it which you can find here:

> https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-remove-sample-data-test-data/

It also contains Enterprise (Commerce) queries.

Comment: Thanks for sharing thing this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861046/how-to-remove-test-orders-from-magento2 . I prefer to use a better delete orders extension https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-delete-orders/ It's free and easy to use again.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of Magento 2 database knowledge will break your system to functioning.

I suggest to try free [**Magento 2 Delete Order extension**](https://www.magespark.com/magento-2-delete-orders.html).