# Migration fails with "Notice: Undefined offset: 1"

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate data from M1 to M2 using the data migration tool. I am using version 1.9.3.10 of M1, and 2.3.0 of M2.

I am using [this info](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/magento-2-how-to-truncate-customers-products-reviews-and-orders-table) to clear my M2 database before the migration and have run this query on M1 to avoid duplicate keys:

```
update  eav_attribute_set set 
    attribute_set_name=concat(attribute_set_name, '_', entity_type_id) 
    where attribute_set_name = 'Default';
```

Still, I get this error:

```
[magento@host m2_root]$ php71 bin/magento migrate:data --reset  --auto 
    vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.10/config.xml

...
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Inventory Step]: started
[2019-01-30 08:43:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2019-01-30 08:44:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
42% [============>---------------] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:

  Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/m2_root/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step  
  /Eav/Data.php on line 292                                                                                          


migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>
```

I searched a lot about this, but no success. Is there perhaps another way to migrate data?

Comment: which php version available now ?

Comment: @RakeshDonga I am using PHP 7.1

Comment: php version  7.1.3+ ?

Comment: @RakeshDonga 7.1.24

Comment: check my answer @Bart

Comment: Bart, are you resetting your target database each time? Do you have any data in your target database?

Comment: @brentwpeterson yes, using a long `TRUNCATE` list that I found somewhere online.

Comment: @BartFriederichs You should consider dropping and recreating your database if you encounter one of these errors. This will ensure you don't have any stray data