# Magento 2 - How to truncate table using SSH?

Tags: magento2, database, command-line, ssh

I want to truncate database tables using command line.

Any directions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which table and for what purpose?

Comment: I created some bash clone scripts for my dev sites and now trying to truncate all tables that are redundant for my dev site. (previous orders, quotes etc.)

Comment: You should give a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/magento-2-how-to-truncate-customers-products-reviews-and-orders-table

Comment: @amitshree I know how to truncate the tables in the database but I wanted to automate this in my bash script ;) I have the answer now, thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLES="log_customer log_visitor log_visitor_info log_url log_url_info"

for table in ${TABLES}
do
  mysql dbname -e "TRUNCATE TABLE ${table};"
done
```

Comment: magic ;) worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below steps to do easily..

**Step1** : to create one file truncate.php in root, create array with all tables, than array load via foreach with `truncateTable()`.

**Step2** : run file via command line php -f truncate.php

also try with this below url :

```
mysql -Nse 'show tables' db_name | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $table" db_name;done
```

// db_name = database name

https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-truncate-all-tables.html

**hope its work for you**

Comment: hmmm sounds like an option but I have a bash script to clone site and I want to truncate redundant tables (preferably) within the bash script with no additional files :/

Comment: :), may be helpful to you check with above url..

Comment: lol why do you need to truncate all tables??? you love copy-paste? i guess he needs at least core data:)

Comment: Yes, I do not need to truncate ALL tables :D Just tables with redundant data :P