# Magento 2 : Create script to archive orders

Tags: magento2, orders

Is there any way we can archive orders in Magento 2 community edition?
What are the steps to create one?
Which things are needed to manage it?

Comment: does modifying 1 into 01 not fixing it ? Cause i don't think the format is valid neither.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Export orders to a CSV or archive them like the Commerce edition? https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-archive-configure.html

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I am trying to create an API that would archive order not delete it.

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

please use this document for this, it will help you to create the script export order [Configure the order archive](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-archive-configure.html)

[Export orders programmatically with custom data](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-export-orders/)

Comment: I hope it will help you.

Comment: It's for Adobe Commerce only.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stand alone page on root of the magento folder and proceed in this manner :

```
<?php use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; $orderData = getOrderCollection(); echo '<pre>';print_r($orderData);die; function getOrderCollection()
{
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($order->getData());die;      
    foreach($order as $_order)
    {
        $orderData[$_order->getId()]['customer_firstname'] = $_order->getData('customer_firstname');        
        $orderData[$_order->getId()]['customer_lastname'] = $_order->getData('customer_lastname');
        $orderData[$_order->getId()]['customer_email'] = $_order->getData('customer_email');
        $orderItems = $_order->getAllItems();
        foreach($orderItems as $item)
        {
            //echo '<pre>';print_r($item->getData());die;                       
            $orderData[$_order->getId()][$item->getId()]['item_name'] = $item->getName();
        }

    }
    return $orderData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is free extension available - https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-delete-orders.html.

Answer (score 0):

I created custom script for delete order.

=> pub/deleteorde.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
$order_ids = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')->getData();
if(sizeof($order_ids))
{
   $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
   foreach ($order_ids as $id) {
      $order = $bootstrap->getObjectManager()->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
      $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
      $order->delete();          
      $registry->unregister('isSecureArea');
      echo "order deleted =" .$id;
      echo "<br/>";
   }
}
echo 'Order Deleted';
```

=> Below script is for direct truncate query, before execute it check carefully, and keep DB backup. it will truncate all order related data. if you had created any custom table then push table name in order_tables array.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

$order_tables = array('gift_message','quote','quote_address','quote_address_item','quote_id_mask','quote_item', 'quote_item_option', 'quote_payment',  'quote_shipping_rate',  'reporting_orders',
 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily',  'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly',  'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly',  'sales_creditmemo',  'sales_creditmemo_comment', 
 'sales_creditmemo_grid',  'sales_creditmemo_item',  'sales_invoice',  'sales_invoiced_aggregated',
 'sales_invoiced_aggregated_order',  'sales_invoice_comment',  'sales_invoice_grid',  'sales_invoice_item',
 'sales_order',  'sales_order_address',  'sales_order_aggregated_created',  'sales_order_aggregated_updated',  'sales_order_grid',  'sales_order_item',  'sales_order_payment',  'sales_order_status_history', 
 'sales_order_tax',  'sales_order_tax_item',  'sales_payment_transaction',  'sales_refunded_aggregated',
 'sales_refunded_aggregated_order',  'sales_shipment',  'sales_shipment_comment',  'sales_shipment_grid',
 'sales_shipment_item',  'sales_shipment_track',  'sales_shipping_aggregated',  'sales_shipping_aggregated_order',  'tax_order_aggregated_created',  'tax_order_aggregated_updated');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$truncate = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0";
$connection->query($truncate);   

foreach($order_tables as $order_table)
{
   try
   {
   $connection = $resource->getConnection();
   $tableName = $resource->getTableName($order_table); 
   $truncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE " . $tableName ;;    
   $connection->query($truncate);   
   }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
      echo "failed";
      echo "<br/>";
      echo $e->getMessage();      
      die();
   }
}
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$truncate = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1";
$connection->query($truncate);   
echo "success";
die();
```

reference
[Magento 2: How to truncate customers, products, reviews and orders table](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102936/magento-2-how-to-truncate-customers-products-reviews-and-orders-table)