# magento 2: cleaning customer and order info

Tags: magento2, database, export

I know a solution was posted for this in magento 1: [Clearing Magento after testing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/clearing-magento-after-testing#3703)

I altered this to work for M2 tables, are there any tables I am missing?

#### Magento 2 SQL

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- reset customers
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_int;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_text;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE customer_entity;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_int;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_text;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_varchar;

ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_datetime AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_decimal AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_int AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_text AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_varchar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_datetime AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_decimal AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_int AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_text AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_varchar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
TRUNCATE `sales_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_creditmemo_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_creditmemo_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_creditmemo_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoice_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoice_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoice_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_status_history`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_shipment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_shipment_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_shipment_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_shipment_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_shipment_track`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`; 
TRUNCATE `wishlist`;  
TRUNCATE `report_event`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_payment_transaction` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

#### Note:

I see that a [plugin](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#stripped-database-dump) exists that does this for M1, does one exist for M2?

Comment: Can manage from Admin right?

Comment: this is magento version of magerun https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2/ you can post issue to "need help to port "