# Magento 2.2.4 : Unable to select all products in backend. Only visable

Tags: magento2.2.4

In the product grid, I want to disable 2000 products.

I'm only able to do so 200 at a time or whatever is visible."20,30.50,200".

I'm "selecting All" and not just selecting "select visible".

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are only able to delete "all visible". Works like a kind of protection to not allow you to delete things important that you can't see.
Another way is to clear all magento database. There are some tutorials explaining how to do it. I found this that may help

[Clearing Magento after testing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/clearing-magento-after-testing)

Comment: I have been able to select all for every version of magneto since 1.* to 2.1 is this a new thing in 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Any tips for this yet?
I'm trying to change attribute from all filtered products, but it keeps updating only the ones that that shows on that page. Frustrating bug :(