# Magento 2.3.2 : How to clear magento database after testing

Tags: database, magento2.3

I am currently doing a lot of tests in Magento so I can get familiar with it. Unfortunately the database is extremely cluttered with my tests. I wish to clear up the database so I can start over again. This means doing the following:

- Clearing all products
- Clearing all attributes
- Clearing all attribute sets
- Clearing all categories
- Clearing all orders, shipments, transactions etc.

I have found solution here : [Clearing Magento after testing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/clearing-magento-after-testing) but its for Magento 2.1

Can anyone help for Magento 2.3.2?