# how to SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 in phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, foreign-key

I am trying to truncate some mySQL tables from phpMyAdmin web interface, but for foreign keys constraint I am not able to do it.  Is there a way to `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You must drop any foreign key constraints first to drop table.
For example, if table name "**customer_group**" and foreign key constraint **entity_id**. Here you need to remove first "**entity_id**" then **customer_group**.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a full query for it?

Comment: @hln You may find this URL helpful.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/#:~:text=Drop%20MySQL%20foreign%20key%20constraints,after%20the%20ALTER%20TABLE%20keywords.

Answer (score 0):

To disable foreign key constraints when you want to truncate a table:

Use **`FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and remember to enable it when you’re done:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**Or you can use** **`DISABLE KEYS:`**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS;
```

Again, remember to enable if thereafter:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE KEYS;
```

If you don’t want to turn key checking on and off, you can permanently modify it to **`ON DELETE SET NULL`**:

Delete the current foreign key first:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name1 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name1; 
ALTER TABLE table_name2 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name2;
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Thanks, I will need to truncate many tables like the link here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3701/clearing-magento-after-testing. But in phpMyAdmin SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 does not work. So is there a easy way to do it?

Comment: This is best way first disable table `FOREIGN_KEY` and after truncate and after enable. Thanks...